# Acronym function without loop on javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to write an acronym function that yields the acronym of whatever I put as my value. I cannot use a loop, but I can use map, reduce, or filter as well as join and split. I have been able to get the acronym of an array, but that's not what I am supposed to do. This should work when trying a value to get its acronym--> acronym(I know, right?) this turns to "ikr."

You don't need to give me the code; I want to know what I can use that is not a loop to get this code to work.

Comment: Hint: use either `.split()` then `.map()` then `.join()`, OR `.split()` then `.reduce()`.

Comment: But `map` **is** a loop inside.

Comment: Are you allowed to use regexps? Are the words always separated by spaces?

Comment: I am not allowed to. What I meant when I wrote that I can't use loops refers to "for, while, etc.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function acronymn( str ) {
    return str.split( /\b(?=[a-z])/ig ) // split on word boundaries
      .map( token => token[0] )         // get first letter of each token
      .join( '' ).toLowerCase()         // convert to lowercase string
    ;
}

acronymn( 'I know, right?' ) === 'ikr' // true
```

Comment: note: `/\b(?=[a-z])/ig` would work for text like `'I know,right?'`

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative:

```
function acronym(str) {
    return str.toLowerCase().match(/(\b[a-z])/g).join('')
}
```

Though, `.match` does not seem to be in the list of allowed methods